# How do I use a formula to count the number of characters in a text field?

Tags: text, count, numbers, salesforce

I would like to use an `IF()` statement if the number of characters in the field is greater than 4. If so, apply another if statement, if not, then `null`.

i have already tried `LEN()` and `FIND()`.

my theory:

```
If(company_website__c)>4),company_website__c,null))
```

but i need to convert the company website into a number value first based on the number of characters.

Comment: I'm unsure of what you are asking. Are you asking to count the number of characters in a field like the title is suggesting, or are you just asking how to check for more than 4? Are you having problems with the nested IF statement at all?

Comment: thanks for your reply. i can figure out the if statement, but i need the first piece of logic to imply the if statement based on the number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Like that?

```
IF(LEN(company_website__c) > 4,
    IF(your other if, goes, here),
    null
)
```